# Why do I get a ParseException in this date? Android kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, error-handling

So I'm creating a function to see whether a date format is valid or not according to the time format that I have set. The function looks like this:

```
    private fun isDateInvalid(time: String, timeFormat: String): Boolean {
    return try {
        val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(timeFormat, Locale.getDefault())
        dateFormat.isLenient = false
        dateFormat.parse(time)
        false
    } catch (e: ParseException){
        Log.d("Tag",e.toString())
        true
    }
}
```

So in this function I pass in parameters for the `time` as `"07:45"` and the `timeFormat` to be `HH:MM`. What did I do wrong?

Comment: `MM` stands for month when `mm` for minutes.

Comment: Also, `isLenient()` is just a `get` method. You should use `setLenient()` or `lenient` as a property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your `timeFormat`. **MM** stands for "month" and **mm** for "minutes". Also, consider changing `isLenient` to `setLenient()`.

Here is a small program that I have tested:

```
import java.util.Locale
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.text.ParseException

fun isDateInvalid(time: String, timeFormat: String): Boolean {
    return try {
        val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(timeFormat, Locale.getDefault())
        dateFormat.setLenient(false)
        dateFormat.parse(time)
        false
    }
    catch (e: ParseException) {
        true
    }
}

fun main() 
{
    println("Date format is ${!isDateInvalid("07:45", "HH:mm")}")
    println("Date format is ${!isDateInvalid("07-45", "HH:mm")}")
}
```

Output:

```
Date format is true
Date format is false
```